# Cloud storage service for storing private user data

Tags: cloud, parse-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud-storage

I'm working on an app that lets users create data and stuff in the app, and I am interested in adding a paid account that will let users store their work in the cloud, sync stuff between devices, and share projects with other users. Basically I want to provide a service similar to Wunderlist or Evernote, though for a different type of content.

So now my question is, is this a good use case for Google Cloud Storage, Parse, or a similar service?

I'm a little confused by what those services are for. Are they a good fit for what I want to do? Or if not, what are some examples of services or technology I should use for this? I'm also concerned about protected the user's private data. For example, in Parse it seems that the application owner can look at all user data stored in Parse.

*Note: I'm not looking for a software recommendation answer suggesting a specific solution (though specific examples would be appreciated), but more of a general explanation of what I need or should use for my use case.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across an [interesting article on oDesk](https://www.odesk.com/blog/2014/04/building-app-get-know-cloud-platforms/) that discussed cloud services for user data and had some links to various services that do what I want.

Below is a list of cloud services for storage and synchronization of user data, taken from the oDesk article:

> - [Apple's iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/%25E2%2580%258E) (iOS and Mac Only)
> - [Dropbox Sync](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync)
> - [Simperium](http://www.simperium.com/)
> - [Parse Data](http://parse.com/)

Note that iCloud and Dropbox require accounts through their own systems, while Simperium and Parse let you set up and manage your own user accounts through their services.

Simperium at least seems a great fit for storing user data in the cloud.

Another [interesting article I found was case study](https://cloud.google.com/files/Simperium.pdf) about Simperium describing how their cloud app Simplenote originally used Google App Engine to provide their cloud synchronization and storage.

So it seems that Google App Engine/Cloud Storage can also be used to provide good synchronization and storage for an app.